# Creating a scatter plot on radial distance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am working on a data project using NBA advanced analytics stats.

I have a pandas data frame with data about shots taken.
What I would like to do is take the column "SHOT_DIST" which holds the distance from the basket the shot was taken from, and create a scatter plot where the points are scattered evenly across an arch which radius is equal to the shot distance.

a very rough example:

[image: windows paint FTW]

Any thoughts on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a polar plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# sample data
distances = 10*np.random.rand(20)
# evenly spaced angles
thetas = np.linspace(0, np.pi, len(distances))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
plt.scatter(thetas, distances, marker='o', c='r', s=30)
plt.xlim((0, np.pi))
plt.xticks([])  
plt.show()
```

It gives:

[image: polar plot]

If you want to evenly space markers of shots taken at more or less the same distance, you can group the dataframe accordingly and set evenly spaced angles separately for each group.